# Success true but nothing is showing up in my Org

Tags: visual-workflow, sandbox

[image][image]I'm using the workbench to upload some deleted flows to my sandbox so we can fix and re-deploy to production.  I got the instruction how to do this from OwnBackup but they are not working.  It says the job success is true but when I go into my org they aren't there.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your package is not constructed according to the expectations of the Metadata API. Your Flows need to be in a subfolder called `flows`, rather than `Restore Flow`.

You can tell that the Metadata API is not attempting to deploy your Flow now because it shows `Number Components Deployed: 0`. It is not able to locate anything in your deployment package. Correcting the directory structure will fix that issue.

Comment: TAHNK YOU!  I will try this immediately!

Comment: I just added 2 new photos.  I fixed the file see the Archive 4 which was what I get when I zip and unzip... I have it the way you suggested but it's still not working.  I'm trying Sandbox and production with the same results yet it's not deploying anything.

Comment: `flows` needs to be lowercase. Unix filesystems are case sensitive and the Metadata API requires precise adherence to its expectations.